# How to arrayformula index and filter google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

this is my formula that gets my result but the problem is its not array formulated, i always drag it down to get the result.

Get the result of STOCKOUT date which is in column B2:B. Search key is from column C2:C and F2:F.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(FILTER('STOCK OUT'!B:B,'STOCK OUT'!$C:$C=C2,'STOCK OUT'!H:H=F2),1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MAP:

```
=MAP(C2:C10,F2:F10,LAMBDA(c,f,INDEX(FILTER('STOCK OUT'!B:B,'STOCK OUT'!$C:$C=c,'STOCK OUT'!H:H=f),1)))
```

Since you are only returning the first match, you may also consider using a lookup function.